# Phpspreadsheet: Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Row::toArray()

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using phpspreadsheet library and testing the uploaded Excel file. These are my codes

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$excel_file = $_FILES['excelFile']['tmp_name'];
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile($excel_file);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($excel_file);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cell_values = $row->toArray();
    if (empty($cell_values[0]) || empty($cell_values[1]) || empty($cell_values[2])) {
        $error = 'Error: Date, Sample and Isolate columns must not be empty in row ' . $row->getRowIndex();
        error_log($error, 3, $log_file);
    }
}
```

I am seeing this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Row::toArray()  on the line that corresponds to
`foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {  $cell_values = $row->toArray();`

What is the issue? Please help me.